# file.copy in R - read only permission denied

Tags: r

I'm trying to copy a bunch of files using file.copy in R with overwrite = TRUE and copy.mode = TRUE. It however keeps failing when trying to overwrite the files giving a warning message of

```
In file.copy(...) problem copying ... to ... Permission denied
```

despite having full read and write permission. If I do the copy manually then it works fine.

I believe this is being caused because the destination folder is tagged as read only after some read only files are being copied over. Is there a way to force the folder to always be non-read only or somehow allow R to actually overwrite read only files?

Comment: Does your code actually create a new folder or is the folder already there? Because right-click on folder and unclick on read-only did the trick for me.

Comment: @Gainz yep that does the trick for me too, but I was hoping to avoid doing that before running the script. The folder is created manually not by the script.

Comment: I see, it is indeed annoying to doing that everytime.